# 'Connection string "SQLServerConnectionString" was not found.' - Using Azure DB

Tags: asp.net, azure, razor

Basically, I'm busy with a university project and this is the error I keep running into. I've tried multiple solutions from Microsoft's sites, but got nothing.

I added the connection string to my web.config, however, it still doesn't come through for me.
The connection link I took directly off of Azure's connection strings, on the DB I created.

[image]

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add
      name="SQLServerConnectionString"
      connectionString= "Server=tcp:[dblink],1433;Initial Catalog=SACLADB;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=[id];Password=[pass];MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The code used to attempt and connect the database which should use the web.config connection string.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Papers";
    var db = Database.Open("SQLServerConnectionString");
    var selectQueryString = "Select * FROM Papers ORDER BY Author";
}
```

Comment: I changed my connection code in the view with;

`var connStr =` `WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;`
    `var selectQueryString = "Select * from Papers ORDER BY Author";`

Now the error comes by; `@foreach (var row in connStr.Query(selectQueryString))` where Query isn't being read. "String does not contain a definition for "Query".

Answer (score 0):

Found the error of my ways;

I was editing the wrong Web.Config. I wasn't editing the one in the root folder where it reads the connection strings, however, all issues are now fixed.